# Getting Positioning Error in here sdk flutter initially

Tags: flutter, google-maps, here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

I'm using here sdk in my flutter application to get map features in my app. When I'm trying to get user's current location then initially for some time, it is showing me this error which is not a good impression for my application.

[image]

It is giving me this error until it finds the location which is represented as this indicator[image]

I've added all the required permissions for that

[image]

but still its giving the location after some delays which is not what I want....

I guess its related to refresh token, which is internally managed by HERE SDK, I'm not able to explicitly add that token , I've provided the consent permission but the token thing is delaying its update, maybe I'm wrong.

These are some code snippets,,,,

This is a gist of navigation example -
https://gist.github.com/alemantrix-settyl/5bff0bb621dd53b8309605dba9613f0c

This is calculating the route and starting the navigation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbm0p.png)

To get more information about the code, visit this repo:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app

Comment: Could you please give some code snippet of your implimentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited this question to clear everything, pls let me know, Is there something else missing?